Setting Up Environment for Open Source - Mismatch Between Guide and What I see on Github (SSH)
I want to get started contributing to open source projects. I have been viewing a guide from Kent Dobbs on Egghead.io.
Here is a screenshot of the part of a part of video series where he instructs to copy and paste the SSH url after forking a repository.

When doing it myself on Github, I do not see how to copy the SSH url.
See image:

My main issue is that the SSH button that appeared in the video is not on Github when I use it, likely since this video was recorded years ago.
I have tried searching the Github page for the SSH url, but I cannot find it.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

You're right, the UI in the video is an older version of the UI. The links to clone a repository can now be found under the big green Code button. You'll also find other options to get the code, such as downloading a ZIP file, opening the repository in the GitHub desktop app or Visual Studio, or by launching a codespace.


SSH isn't the "old way". It's the more secure option since https wouldn't use asymmetric encryption

Fair point, I've removed that bit.
